# How long will my mild back pain last?

Tags: pain, back, muscle

I've started lifting like a month and a half ago but about a week ago my mid back and sometimes my lower has a mild pain. It usually hurts when i straighten my back in a sitting position. My lower back feels fine but when i touch my left hip i can feel the pain. I can walk fine and my lower back doesnt hurt.
I'm 19 and never experienced back problems.
 - List item

Comment: I think deadlifting for first time caused this. Should i continue to lift?

Comment: This is not something that can really be diagnosed over the internet, I would recommend that you see a health care professional.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When doing weight lifting exercises, you must also include [core exercises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUjFh4J1dnchttp) in your routine to prevent back problems. Of course, this is in addition of making sure you do the weightlifting in an appropriate way. It's best to let experts monitor you in a gym until you have enough experience to do it all by yourself. And all this applies to someone who hasn't got back problems to begin with. In your case, your back problems requires some evaluation by an expert, if only to make sure you can continue to exercise.

Comment: That is a good idea. Ive lost 6 kg by doing cardio and weights and never thought abot working out abs. If i work out abs from now on will it be beneficial.

Comment: How would this prevent back problems? No possible commentary on bad form, over lifting, too much weight, poor shoes, etc? This is vague advice that sounds good and has a general benefit but overall really doesn't mean much.

Comment: @JohnP I added more about the issues you raised.